# Return value from callback in function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, return, synchronous

Hello i would like to return a simple Boolean with there options:
- true: user exists in database
- false: user doesn't exists in database

Here's my non-working code:

```
database.users.get("test-username", function (err, value) {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    } else {
        return value;
    }
})
```

The return is always `undefined`
I know that NodeJS is designed to work async, but async functions don't allow me to return something. I'm stuck, please help!

Also, i use `LevelUP` as database system.
(if my problem have no solution, is there an other database system in NodeJS that allow synchronous?)

Thanks to the community!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you get anything back when you console.log your return?
for example:

```
function dbCall(){    
database.users.get("test-username",function(err, value){
     if(err){
          return false;
     }else{
         console.log(value);
         return value;
     }
}
}
```

if you get something in value then the reason you don't see anything in return is because the api call is asynchronous. You'll have to make a promise.

```
new Promise(resolve,reject){
    let data = dbCall();
    if(data == false)
         reject(data);
    else
         resolve(data);
}
```

Comment: Sure, console.log works in callback, outside the callback nothing works.
I found another solution, is to call function with `req` and `res` parameters (ExpressJS), so i can display response directly with `res.send(response)` in callback

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because your program does not wait for a async call to be called back before continuing. But yes req and res should work too :)
However is you do need to do more complicated operations using the data, I highly recommend you look up promises and async js library.

Comment: Yes, i finally used Promise
Thanks for your help!